# Get max of grouped documents in CosmosDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-sdk-for-java

I want to query **Azure CosmosDb** documents with **SQL API** query. These Documents shall be filtered and grouped by specific values. From these groups only the document with a specified max value shall be returned.

### Example

#### Azure CosmosDb Documents

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "someValue": "shall be included",
  "group": "foo",
  "timestamp": "1668907312"
}
```

```json
{
  "id": "2",
  "someValue": "shall be included",
  "group": "foo",
  "timestamp": "1668907314"
}
```

```json
{
  "id": "3",
  "someValue": "shall be included",
  "group": "bar",
  "timestamp": "1668907312"
}
```

```json
{
  "id": "4",
  "someValue": "don't include",
  "group": "bar",
  "timestamp": "1668907312"
}
```

#### Query

I want do get all documents

- with `"someValue": "shall be included"`
- grouped by `group`
- from group only max of `timestamp`

#### Example response

```json
{
  "id": "2",
  "someValue": "shall be included",
  "group": "foo",
  "timestamp": "1668907314"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "someValue": "shall be included",
  "group": "bar",
  "timestamp": "1668907312"
}
```

### Question

What is the best way to do this? It would be **optimal** if

- it is possible in one query
- and executable with Azure SDK with use of [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.models.sqlparameter?view=azure-java-stable) (to prevent injection)

### What i've tried

My current approach consists of 2 queries and uses `ARRAY_CONTAINS`, which does not allow the use of [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.models.sqlparameter?view=azure-java-stable) for the document paths.

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "some-value": "shall be included",
  "group": "foo",
  "timestamp": "1668907314"
}
```

#### First Query

```sql
SELECT c.group AS group
    MAX(c.timestamp) AS maxValue
    FROM c
    WHERE c.someValue = 'shall be included'
    GROUP BY c.group
```

#### Second Query

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(
        <RESULT-FIRST-QUERY>,
        {
        "group": c.group,
        "maxValue": c.timestamp
        },
        false
    )
```

Answer (score -3):

I would utilize the MAX() [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/aggregate-max) in conjunction with GROUP BY i.e

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.someValue = "shall be included"
GROUP BY c.group
HAVING MAX(c.timestamp)
```

Haven't run that yet/need to make a collection, but seems like it should do the trick...

Comment: Unfortunately, CosmosDb does not allow `*` in `GROUP BY`. It also does not know `HAVING`.